# Flush iCache in x86

Tags: caching, x86, intel, flush

Is there anyway I can flush iCache in x86 architecture ? Like WBINVD which will invalidate and flush all the cachelines in data cache.

Comment: I seem to recall that you can do a "far" jump (i.e. like `jmpf 0x8:blah`), but I can't find a cite in the intel manuals at the moment.

Comment: On second though (sorry too late to edit) I think a better way would be to do it indirectly like by calling mprotect on the relevant region or something.

Comment: @user786653: maybe you're thinking of `jmp` making self-modifying code safe by flushing the CPU's prefetch queue on early x86, like 8086?  Even near `jmp` is fine. (And a CS selector of 0 isn't special, AFAIK).  Modern x86 uarches snoop the physical address of instructions in the pipeline so there's no way to execute stale instructions in practice, giving a stronger guarantee than what's on paper (and what's guaranteed to be safe in the future).  [Observing stale instruction fetching on x86 with self-modifying code](//stackoverflow.com/q/17395557).  And i-cache is coherent with data caches.

Comment: But anyway, I don't think a CS selector of `0` will do anything special like flush instruction caches.  And if you meant real mode where the segment register is just a value instead of an index into the GDT + the low bits being the privilege level, then certainly not.  Jumping doesn't flush caches,  Neither does `mprotect`: modifying the page tables and using `invlpg` doesn't evict data from caches because they're physically addressed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, **[`wbinvd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wbinvd) flushes and invalidates *all* caches**, not just data and unified caches.  (I'm not sure if that includes TLBs if you ran it with paging enabled.)

---

What are you trying to test?  L1i miss / L2 hit for code-fetch?  I don't think it's possible to purposely flush *just* the I-cache without also flushing all levels of cache.

You could create conflict misses for a specific line by executing code at 8 addresses that alias it, assuming an 8-way 32kiB L1i cache.  But cache replacement is usually pseudo-LRU, not true LRU, so you might want to jump through a set of more than 8 aliasing lines a couple times to make sure.

---

**[`clflush`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/clflush) / `clflushopt` should do the trick for a specific cache line**.  They're required to flush the line from *all* levels of cache in all cores.

I assume they would also evict decoded uops from the (virtually addressed) uop cache.

> The CLFLUSH instruction can be used at all privilege levels and is subject to all permission checking and faults associated with a byte load (and **in addition, a CLFLUSH instruction is allowed to flush a linear address in an execute-only segment**). Like a load, the CLFLUSH instruction sets the A bit but not the D bit in the page tables.

---

**But if you want this correctness after JIT-compiling something**, merely jumping or calling to the newly-written instructions is sufficient to avoid stale instruction fetch.

(In fact, on current x86 implementations, they snoop stores to any code address in the pipeline, so you'll never see stale instruction fetch even when you have the same physical page mapped to different virtual addresses, and write one while executing the other.  [Observing stale instruction fetching on x86 with self-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17395557))

---

You only need to worry about your compiler optimizing away "dead stores" to a buffer you cast to a function pointer.  In GNU C / C++, use `__builtin___clear_cache` on the range of bytes you wrote.  It compiles to zero instructions on x86 (unlike ARM or other ISAs with non-coherent instruction caches), but it is still needed to not optimize away stores of instruction bytes:  [How does __builtin___clear_cache work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741814/how-does-builtin-clear-cache-work#comment85964322_35741869)

Comment: I don't think __builtin___clear_cache() has a memory barrier effect! It's not true.

Comment: @ChangbinDu: I didn't say it was a barrier, either run-time or compiler.  On x86, it doesn't give any ordering, just prevents dead-store elimination, which is also necessary. (On ISAs like ARM where it needs some asm instructions, it will involve some run-time barrier instructions like `dmb` or maybe `dsb`, but it probably still doesn't prevent compile-time reordering except wrt. calling through function pointers.)

Comment: It does prevent dead-store elimination, but that is not __builtin___clear_cache designed to do. Any non-pure function that accepts the pointer has that effect. See examples https://godbolt.org/z/Yxr5WG84o