# Does clflush flush L1i?

Tags: assembly, caching, x86, intel, clflush

This is the question: Does clflush flush L1i? Intel ISA manual was not clear on that:

> Invalidates from every level of the cache hierarchy in the cache
>   coherence domain the cache line that contains the linear address
>   specified with the memory operand. If that cache line contains
>   modified data at any level of the cache hierarchy, that data is
>   written back to memory

I would speculate by the wording

> If that cache line contains modified **data** at any level of the
>   cache hierarchy, that **data** is written back to memory.

So L1I left untouched. Is it the actual behavior of Intel CPUs?

Comment: It appears L1i lines are also evicted. Running `perf stat -e mem_load_retired.l1_miss,frontend_retired.l1i_miss` with the program [here](https://pastebin.com/9MD9inDR) will show about 10M L1d and L1i miss when lin 12 is *not* commented. Otherwise only 2K misses are reported (for both caches).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks for the comment, but may I ask you why you used `mfence`. `clflush` (unlike `clflushopt`) has strict memory ordering guarantees.

Comment: Oops, I didn't remember which was ordered and which was not. Thank you for remembering me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`clflush` does what it says on the tin and flushes all caches: instruction, data, and unified.**  (And the decoded-uop cache).  Margaret Bloom actually [tested to confirm this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360640/does-clflush-flush-l1i#comment110290909_62360640).

Instruction caches can't ever be dirty so it makes sense that discussion of modified lines talks about data.  Only write-back data caches can be dirty. Note that one of the intended purposes of `clflush` is to write-back dirty data to a non-volatile DIMM, so it's natural that the docs focus on data.

You're reading too much into the wording, perhaps based on a misconception that write-back is synonymous with flushing.  **A clean cache line (such as I-cache) can be flushed by simply dropping it, no write-back necessary.**  Note the difference between [`invd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/invd) and [`wbinvd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wbinvd).  The `invd` docs use "flush" as a synonym for "invalidate".  (related: [What use is the INVD instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775371/what-use-is-the-invd-instruction))

---

From Intel's vol.2 ISA ref manual [entry for `clflush`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/clflush)

> The CLFLUSH instruction can be used at all privilege levels and is subject to all permission checking and faults associated with a byte load (and in addition, a CLFLUSH instruction is **allowed to flush a linear address in an execute-only segment**). Like a load, the CLFLUSH instruction sets the A bit but not the D bit in the page tables.

This doesn't *explicitly* say that it actually flushes I-cache in such regions, but it implies that flushing is relevant for such cases where data accesses aren't even possible.

Semi-related: [Flush iCache in x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854283/flush-icache-in-x86)