# Why does the risc-v doc 'snoop the instruction cache on data cache miss' instead of snooping the data cache?

Tags: caching, jit, riscv, memory-barriers

In risc-v official [doc](https://riscv.org/technical/specifications/) 'Unprivileged Specification version 20191213', p31 says:

> The FENCE.I instruction was designed to support a wide variety of implementations. A sim-
> ple implementation can flush the local instruction cache and the instruction pipeline when the
> FENCE.I is executed. A more complex implementation might snoop the **instruction (data)** cache
> on every **data (instruction)** cache miss

It seems to mean that data cache miss will search instruction cache (normally L1I cache). It seems to be conflict with instruction cache [designed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Overview) function although in general instruction and data are all binary data.

---

Then I found this [Arm blog](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/caches-and-self-modifying-code), it make sense of the situation that we **snoop the data cache** on instruction cache miss in JIT because the instruction are modified and corresponding instruction cache is *invalidated*.

Q1: Is there other conditions that we should snoop the data cache on the instruction cache miss?

I also found this [Q&A comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/438294/what-information-exactly-does-an-instruction-cache-store#comment1095728_438298). In modern CISC cpu (Although risc-v is MISC. Here CISC is said in this lwn [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/252125/)), L1I cache is indeed the trace cache (i.e. micro-op cache). So I guess maybe decoded micro-op has useful **data** which can be used in resolving **data cache miss**.

Q2: Is my guess right? Also, is there other conditions that we should snoop the instruction cache on the data cache miss?

Comment: Snooping makes fences cheaper.  The less you track, the more it costs to guarantee that a fence gives its guarantees, e.g. worst case flush everything.  In a related case on x86 (where I-cache coherence is required on paper only on jumps, real CPUs snoop always, because nuking the pipeline on every jump would be too expensive.  ([Observing stale instruction fetching on x86 with self-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388700))

Comment: Also, no, L1i isn't a decoded-uop cache; that's only useful on x86 where decode is expensive.  And even then (https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/4/), the uop cache is L0, separate from L1i, and it's not a trace cache, just a uop cache organized by address of the instructions they were decoded from, not threading jumps.  (Except on Pentium 4, where L1i was a trace cache.  It was bad.  Low capacity made worse by being a trace cache which could cache the same instructions twice for different branching paths, and legacy decode was slow on L1i miss.)

Comment: Thanks. The above comments can answer why risc-v use snoop with fence, but why do risc-v snoop the **instruction** cache on every data cache miss instead of snooping the **data** cache? Maybe I didn't describe the question clearly. I have updated it.

Comment: If it didn't snoop the I-cache, it wouldn't know if there were dirty lines in the D-cache that were also valid in the I-cache.  `fence.i` syncs instructions and data, right?  Like after JIT storing some instructions into a buffer, run `fence.i` before jumping to that buffer?  Or does the JIT also have to run instructions to force write-back of specific cache lines (to some unified level of cache) before that, like I think ARM does?  I don't know RISC-V very well so I don't know what ISA requirements the HW has to meet, or what typical implementation strategies are.

Comment: Do you mean that it snoops the I-cache to catch the instruction like `STR Ra, [Rb, imm]` which will maybe change instruction and update D-cache? If so, I understand the problem.

Comment: So it will notice self-modifying code **more quickly** (the quick detection is similar to **bypass** in some way.). Otherwise it will snoop the D-cache which may stores the modified instruction **afterwards**. Then it may write-back by `dc cvau` when one specific instruction in I-cache has been invalidated by `ic ivau` (the latter two arm instructions are got from this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70635862)).