How to resolve EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2) when access to mmap allocated excutable page? on Apple silicon(MacOS & M1 mac mini)
I have written a test program to implement something similar to self-modifying code on Apple Silicon.
int main() {
 
    uint8_t *instr;
    uint32_t instr1 = 0x8b000000; // add x0, x0, x0
    uint32_t instr2 = 0xd65f03c0; // ret
 
    if(pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np() == 1)
        printf("jit write supported\n");
    else
        printf("jit write not supported\n");

    pthread_jit_write_protect_np(1);
    instr = (uint8_t*)mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_JIT, 0, 0) + 4084;
    pthread_jit_write_protect_np(0);

    if(instr == MAP_FAILED){
        perror("mmap");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("instr addr : %lx\n", (uintptr_t)instr);
    memcpy(instr, &instr, 4);
    memcpy(instr+4, &instr2, 4);

    printf("instr1 is %x\n", *(uint32_t *)instr);
    printf("instr2 is %x\n", *(uint32_t *)(instr+4));

    asm volatile(
    "eor x0, x0, x0\n"
    "eor x1, x1, x1\n"
    "eor x2, x2, x2\n"
    "eor x3, x3, x3\n"
    );

    asm volatile(
    "ldr x1, %[ptr]\n"
    "br x1\n"
    ::[ptr]"m"(instr)
    );

    return 0;
}

I allocate a 4KB memory region with mmap, allowing read, write, and execute permissions. Then, I use memcpy to write the two assembly instructions to this memory region. After that, I initialize registers x1~x3 with inline assembly and branch the program counter (pc) to the previously allocated page. After branching, execute instructions instr1 and instr2 sequentially. However, when branching and accessing memory region, the program aborts with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 error.
Through Google searches, I've come to realize that the issue lies with Apple codesign. It seems that access is denied for code running in memory on Apple Silicon if it is not codesigned. So, I've been googling to find a way to allow access through codesign. However, I have been unable to find a way to codesign the memory allocated through mmap to allow access. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

You have some other bugs that may or may not be related, but would certainly be capable of causing segfaults on their own.  (1) Your inline assembly doesn't declare its register clobbers.  In particular, making function calls from inline asm is problematic because it not only clobbers registers, but also the red zone, which AFAIK there is no way to declare as clobbered.  If possible, use a function pointer instead.

(2) On ARM64 the instruction and data cache are not unified, so you have to flush them after writing your code into memory before you can safely execute it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70635862/synchronizing-caches-for-jit-self-modifying-code-on-arm/70684882#70684882

(3) You jump to your code using br which does not save a return address in the link register, so ret will not get you back.  You probably wanted blr, but as noted above, better still to use a function pointer and call it directly from C instead of from asm.

(4) pthread_jit_write_protect_np(0); leaves execution in a denied state, according to https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/pthread_jit_write_protect_np.3.html.  So you presumably have to call it again with 1 after writing your code, before you can execute it.  This might also take care of the cache flushing I mentioned in (2); not sure about that.

Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/porting-just-in-time-compilers-to-apple-silicon.  It explains how the code signing issue is dealt with, as well as the cache flushing.

Oh, and btw: eor x0, x0, x0 is not the best way to zero a register on ARM.  We do that on x86 for various historical reasons, but they don't apply on ARM.  mov x0, #0 or mov x0, xzr are perfectly fine. In fact eor x0, x0, x0 is worse because it has a false input dependency.

Thank you for the nice explanation. Thanks to that, my knowledge of the ARM64 architecture and apple silicon has been further enhanced.

The immediate issue is that you call pthread_jit_write_protect_np(0) and never flip it back to 1. This leaves your thread in a state where JIT pages are rw-, so trying to execute from there will fault. Call pthread_jit_write_protect_np(1) after the memcpy()s.
The next issue is that you use ldr x1, %[ptr]. This loads x1 from the pointer rather than moving the pointer into x1, so x1 will be the 8 bytes you wrote. Replace that with mov x1, %[ptr] and change "m" to "r".
Then there's caching. Import <libkern/OSCacheControl.h> and do a sys_dcache_flush(instr, 0x8) before the final call to pthread_jit_write_protect_np(1) and a sys_icache_invalidate(instr, 0x8) afterwards.
Then there's the issue that you're writing the wrong thing:
memcpy(instr, &instr, 4);

You meant to take the address of instr1 here, not instr. You're currently writing the low 4 bytes of the pointer.
Now your shellcode is being copied correctly and actually executes, but the ret is a problem. You call into it with br, so x30 is stale and points to wherever the last function returned to, which is most likely your last printf. Change br to blr.
And then - why do you map 0x400 bytes but then add 0xff4 to that pointer? In practice that is likely to not be a problem because pages under arm64 XNU are 16KiB, but just... why? You could at the very least not add anything to the pointer, then any size big enough to hold your instructions would be fine.
And then there's the missing register clobbers, which may just happen to not cause problems right now, but sooner or later that will interfere with code generated by the compiler.

It was resolved thanks to the clear explanation. The original intention was to allocate memory using mmap with a page size appropriate for the operating system, and then use memcpy to place two instructions at the end of the page. The following code seems to fit my intent. bold instr = (uint8_t*)mmap(NULL, 0x4000, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_JIT, 0, 0) + 0x3ff8;
